# How to add a new field to a firestore collection when offline with flutter?

Tags: mobile, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using flutter and Google firestore and I need to update a collection (add a new field), when offline, I'm testing using airplane mode. When I click in the button the app crashes and the data is not sent to the database. It works fine online.

I think this happen because the async/await, however if I don't use them, the app doesn't even save when online.

Widget where the is the function that calls the update function (I'm using FutureBuilder):

```
var formataData = new DateFormat('y/MM/dd');
var data = formataData.format(new DateTime.now());
final _funcao = funcoesBanco();

 child: RaisedButton(
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
   child: Text(
    "Registrar", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),),
    onPressed: () {
     _funcao.atualizaCampos(data, 'saida1', snapshot.data[index]);
    },
   ),
```

The update function:

```
atualizaCampos(String dataHoraAtual, String campo, DocumentSnapshot document){
    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async{
      DocumentSnapshot freshSnap = await transaction.get(document.reference);
      await transaction.update(freshSnap.reference , {
        campo: dataHoraAtual,
      });
    });
  }
```

The expected result would be the data added to the firestore, even when offline.

The errors I get in the console:

```
V/NativeCrypto(19561): Read error: ssl=0x740b0778c8: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort
V/NativeCrypto(19561): Write error: ssl=0x740b0778c8: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
V/NativeCrypto(19561): Write error: ssl=0x740b0778c8: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
I/OkHttpClientTransport(19561): Failed closing connection

E/flutter (19561): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing transaction, java.lang.Exception: Do transaction failed., null)
```

Comment: "When I click in the button the app crashes and the data is not sent to the database." Please find the exact error message and stack trace in the debug output, and add them to your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'vd added the errors it prints out in the console, after this, the app just close.

Comment: Hmm... that doesn't mean a lot to me. Is there some nested exception from the Android/iOS side of things?

Comment: Nope, I've also checked if .hasErrors too, but it returns false. Maybe it's because the device is offline and I'm using runTransaction?

Comment: Ah, transactions definitely only work when you have a network connection, so that would explain. I'd like to see it expose a better error message, but it's definitely not going to work while you're offline.

Comment: I've updated my function, to just     _firestore.collection('horarios').document(document).updateData(novoCampo);
the function recieves the document ID, and now it works offline too, at least as far as aI tested it. Thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 1):

I've just figured it out, the Widget is now like this (changed the onPressed):

```
var formataData = new DateFormat('y/MM/dd');
var data = formataData.format(new DateTime.now());
final _funcao = funcoesBanco();
final docID = snapshot.data[index].reference.documentID;

 child: RaisedButton(
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
   child: Text(
    "Registrar", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),),
    _funcao.atualizaCampos(docID,{
     'saida2': data
    });
   ),
```

And the function is like this:

```
atualizaCampos(document, novoCampo){
 _firestore.collection('horarios').document(document).updateData(novoCampo);
}
```